# Binding arguments to a bean in spring

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I made a class (named it iperfAndroidApp) which implements some interface (named it AppService), and made another class which uses this iperfAndroidApp (Named it IperfApp) .the IperfApp should be an API for other project.
I made all this to be able to replace between Android instance to IOS for example in the future.
I want that the iperfAndroidApp class will be a bean in the xml file.

and the point I got stack was is that IperfApp get some parameters in the constructor (from the outside project), and I want to bind them to the constructor of that bean so I will not have to use "new"(line 8).

I cutted out the irrelevant parts to ease your read.

```
//THE API THAT I AM CREATING
public class IperfApp {
//THE SERVICE THAT SHOULD BE INITIALIZED WITH ANDROID OR IOS
 AppService iperf;

 //I WANT TO PASS THE ARGUMENTS TO THE BEAN INSTEAD OF USING NEW
 public IperfApp(List<String> udids, List<String> commands, int runTime) {
 iperf=new IperfAndroidApp(udids, commands, runTime);
 }

...
}




//THE BEAN I WANT TO USE
public class IperfAndroidApp extends AndroidApp {

    private AndroidServer androidServer;
    private List<String> commands;
    private int runTime;

    public IperfAndroidApp(List<String> udids, List<String> commands, int runTime) {
        super(udids);
        this.commands = commands;
        this.runTime = runTime;
    }
....
}



public abstract class AndroidApp extends AppClient {...}
public abstract class AppClient implements AppService {...}
```

the bean in spring config file:

```
 <bean id="iperfInstance" 
  class="com.airspan.testspan.smarphones.Client.IperfAndroidApp" scope="singleton">
 <!--  want to bind args from the code here -->
 </bean>
```

I also tried different approach using spring class configuration

```
@Configurable
@ComponentScan("com.airspan.testspan.smarphones")
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class AppConfigurations {
 //--------- to load the config.property file need to initialize it for spring-----------
 @Bean
 public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
 propertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
 return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
 }


 //---------------------Beans of Apps------------------------
 @Bean
 public IperfAndroidApp iperfAppInstance(List<String> udids, List<String> commands, int runTime){
 return new IperfAndroidApp(udids, commands, runTime);
 }

}
public class IperfAppRunner extends AppRunner {
 private AppService iperf;
 public IperfAppRunner(List<String> udids, List<String> commands, int runTime) {
 //iperf = new IperfAndroidApp(udids, commands, runTime);
 iperf=(AppService) context.getBean("iperfAppInstance", udids, commands, runTime);
 }
 ...
}
```

but it does not seems to pass the arguments..

I get this exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'iperfAppInstance' defined in com.airspan.testspan.smarphones.AppConfigurations: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'iperfAppInstance' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List<java.lang.String>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
```

so basically I'm trying to create an object using "spring factory" with some parameters that been given to me.

is it possible to do so ? if so, how?

Comment: Ehm.... you should really start with a simple Spring tutorial. Go and look at this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm.

Comment: I already know about this tutorial.. how is that helping me with the problem?